# Generate csrf token for html page

Tags: javascript, php, html, csrf

Can someone help me with the steps to add a csrf token in a plain html page and how to validate/verify in php.

Am using a plain html page and javascript to perform validation.  Through html page, the user can select the file to upload to the server. On clicking submit button the php is triggered to do the upload function across servers.

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return doCheck('filename');">
<b><font color="#e9b61f">Please choose a file:</font></b> <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"  id="filename" /> <br />
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="R6B7hoBQd0wfG5Y6qOXHPNm4b9WKsTq6Vy6Jssxb"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

Comment: Code Snippet:
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return doCheck('filename');">
<b><font color="#e9b61f">Please choose a file:</font></b> <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"  id="filename" /> <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

Comment: Please fix your code snippet. Also, say what you have tried already and if you have researched anything on the internet at all. There are certain rules that you have to follow to post questions here on stackoverflow, please read them first, you can start from here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi George, Sorry for not elaborating - i have just created this account few mins back - I have tried the below
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="R6B7hoBQd0wfG5Y6qOXHPNm4b9WKsTq6Vy6Jssxb"/> but pressing F12 and going through the headers, req and response param unable to find csrf token value .

More over passing it as query string will lead to know what csrf value we are sending and don't want to do that. 

I have shared only the crux of the code snippet. 
Hope this helps you for answering my question .................

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? Is that token not readable on the server side? Then please share more details about this. Also, how is this question related to Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways to create an anti-CSRF token using PHP is using the session_id() or generate some random string and store it on $_SESSION.

So, when creating the form's HTML you must include:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf-token'])) {
    $_SESSION['csrf-token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(128));
} ?>
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=$_SESSION['csrf-token']?>">
```

Then, when validating:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['_csrf'] != $_SESSION['csrf-token']) {
    http_response_code(403);
    die('Invalid token');
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @rodrigovr, thanks for the inputs - i have added the first code snippet in html form and the second snippet in php file. 

When i click the upload button on html page, the uploader.php is triggered and throwing the response (invalid token).  When i tried to print the value of token in php file like 
echo $a = $_POST['_csrf']; and echo $b = $_SESSION['csrf-token']; - no values are printed. Am not able to see the csrf value by pressing f12 in browser.

Comment: You probably need to "session_start()" before using $_SESSION

Comment: Hi @rodrigovr,  Tried but still not getting getting the required outcome have pasted by html and php page below kindly have a look and let me know if any modifications required.

Comment: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hi</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['csrf-token'])) {
    $_SESSION['csrf-token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(128));
 echo $_SESSION['csrf-token'];
} ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return doCheck('filename');">
<b><font color="#e9b61f">Please choose a file:</font></b> <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" accept=".wav"  id="filename" /> <br />
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<?=$_SESSION['csrf-token']?>">
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </BODY></form></HTML>

Comment: PHP script
<?php
echo $a = $_SESSION['csrf-token'];
echo $b = $_POST['_csrf'];
if ($_POST['_csrf'] != $_SESSION['csrf-token']) {
    http_response_code(403);
    die('Invalid token');
});

$html = "<html><BODY bgcolor='#696969'>";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) ;
$ok=1;
<<<code upload files to servers >>>>

Comment: session_start() is needed at the beginning of both files. You can also set session.auto_start = 1 in php.ini

Comment: Hi @rodrigovr, Added session_start() at both .html and .php files but no luck. When i tried to print the values of $_POST['_csrf'] and $_SESSION['csrf-token'] using echo( echo $_POST['_csrf'] ; $_SESSION['csrf-token']; )no values are getting printed but i could see the the value in request parameter "Cookie: PHPSESSID=ska5gpjmnlgb2oonmn79qjmef3" by pressinng F12